# How do i fix navigationBar disappearing on iOS WKWebView Screen

Tags: ios, swift, angularjs, uikit, wkwebview

My iOS app is an entire WKWebView screen. The WKWebView is just a simple angularJS web application that is designed for mobile. I'm running into an issue where once the user clicks on any textfield on the website through the iOS app the navigation bar disappears and then comes back when the user clicks out of any textField. The navigation bar is apart of angularJS so I can't do something like `navigationController?.hidesBarsWhenKeyboardAppears = false` on the native iOS side because the navBar is built into the website. I noticed android doesn't have this issue so please can someone help me fix this issue for iOS. Here is a screenshot of what i mean
[screenshot of what I mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NbCQX.png)

Answer (score 0):

Have you embed your viewcontroller inside a navigation controller?

Comment: No I have not. The iOS app is only one screen where i have a WKWebView which takes up the entire screen. The navbar is from the web side not from the native iOS side